# How do I make maps that each have different lighting and atmosphere settings in Roblox Studio?

Tags: roblox, roblox-studio

I am trying to make a game on Roblox Studio. It's a horror-ish kind of game with the gameplay taking place in rounds, with the map picked each round. The problem I am having is that some maps (like the swamp) have lighting one way (dark, foggy) and other maps (the city I am planning to make) need to look different. How can I do this? Do I need to have the maps be in separate places within the studio, or is there a way that I can make the game change the atmosphere settings for each map? Thanks for the assistance.